# Not able to move multiple images to a folder in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to move multiple images from one folder to another but nothing is getting moved and no error received. Am using laravel 7.
Here is the form view in html

```
                <form method="post" action="{{url('senddata')}}">//the route
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                <h3>Add Images</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" class="form-control"> </textarea> 
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Images</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control input-sm" name="images[]" multiple>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
               </form>
```

Here is my controller

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{

  public function store(Request $request)
    {
         return Products::create([
         'title'=>$request['title'],
         'description'=>$request['description']
             ]);
           $images= $request['images'];
          foreach ($images as $image):
          $name = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move( public_path().'/images/', $name);    
         if($file){
         $imagedata=Images::create([
        'title'=>$image->getClientOriginalName(),
        'filename'=>$image->getClientOriginalName()
        ]);
          }
          endforeach;

       var_dump('image uploaded');

    }

   // dd($request);
```

The post route

```
Route::post('senddata','ProductsController@store');
```

Comment: I don't see the initial value of `$file` where it is initialized ? Also there is a return statement at the start of your function so it will just create products and rest of the code will not get executed

Comment: @ M Khalid Junaid , I have edited it should be $image

Comment: Put that return statement at the end of your function

Comment: @ M Khalid thanks but now I get an error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string thinking that my code is returning my images as a string how can I solve this

Comment: you are missing the `enctype` attribute for the form tag

Comment: @lagbox how should it appear please